# How to fetch mysql data into html table with vertical header?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to fetch mySQL data into html table with vertical header. My html table code is in the following code :

```
<table border="1" align="center">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <?php  
            while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
                echo "<td>$no</td>";
                $no++;
            }
        ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Term</th>
        <?php  
            while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
                echo "<td>".$row2['term']."</td>";
            }
        ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Normalisasi TF.IDF</th>
        <?php  
            while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
                echo "<td>".$row3['tf_idf_normalisasi']."</td>";
            }
        ?>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Here's screenshot of my table :
[image]

But mySQL data are not displayed on 2nd and 3rd `<tr>`. What is wrong with my code ? Can someone tell me how to make it work ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate `td` elements HTML with a single loop otherwise [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) method returns `NULL` in second and third loop since you are already fetched all rows.

```
<?php  
    $td1 = '';
    $td2 = '';
    $td3 = '';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
        $td1 .= "<td>$no</td>";
        $td2 .= "<td>" . $row['term'] . "</td>";
        $td3 .= "<td>" . $row['tf_idf_normalisasi'] . "</td>";
        $no++;
    }
?>

<table border="1" align="center">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <?php echo $td1; ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Term</th>
        <?php echo $td2; ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Normalisasi TF.IDF</th>
        <?php echo $td3; ?>
    </tr>
</thead>
```